# Are there any limitations to SVGs in Salesforce?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, svg-icon, svg

I am trying to display an SVG in a Lighting Web Component. I have noticed that the SVG is not rendering properly, and removing filter="url(#filter0_d)" in the g tag fixes the issue. This holds true for Safari and Chrome. Why does removing this fix the issue? Are there any similar limitations to SVGs in Salesforce?

Any response is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that id values in Lightning are modified to be globally unique, so it can be challenging to get the Id fragment correct. It is true that [SVGs are restricted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_svg_in_component), but this is mostly just a mismatched ID problem. I don't have a specific solution to this problem, as only ID values are supported, and LWC "manages" them for us, making it hard to predict what the final ID would be. It might be worth logging a bug with Salesforce and seeing if they can get it fixed somehow (probably by patching `url()` to match the generated ID of the element).

Answer (score -1):

> Your problem is that id values in Lightning are modified to be globally unique, so it can be challenging to get the Id fragment correct. It is true that SVGs are restricted, but this is mostly just a mismatched ID problem. I don't have a specific solution to this problem, as only ID values are supported, and LWC "manages" them for us, making it hard to predict what the final ID

For the the problem of regenerated ID by LWC.

I solved the problem by adding a data-id in my SVG. I was able to target the different paths in my image with the help of

event.target.dataset.id

Path's example
`<path id="sf-id_av" data-id="sf-id_av"...`

Comment: Hello, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [answer]. Could you please expand your answer and elaborate more on how this solution could help to resolve the problem?